# roundcube database connection failed

Tags: php, mysql, roundcube

What I thought would be a very simple error turns out trickier than I thought. Here is my config.inc.php

```
$config['db_dsnw'] = 'mysqli://[user]:[pass]@localhost/[database]';
```

Now for php scripts I'm using mysqli. what did I overlook?

There are no error logs being reported by nginx and PHP parser.

I verified the login by going to terminal and logging in with the actual account.

I verified it has the needed privileges. rebooted my raspberry pi but still can't get past that error.

Comment: Please supply error details. I mean: Why do you think you have error?

Comment: because the database cant connect. as i stated in my OP no error logs are being produced therefor cannot provide any error logs. the only thing i got is the connection string.

Comment: How do you know the db can't connect? maybe it's another issue?

Comment: by the fact that it says in big font "DATABASE ERROR: CONNECTION FAILED!" in big bold capital letters. This is not the first time im dealing with SQL so i know how to do a simply connection string. is the above the correct syntax or if not how do i know which driver is being used. im using mariadb.

Comment: all right. I think you should add the error you get to your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I work with mysql db and connection string starts with jdbc: can it be your issue?

Comment: tried jdbc and got 500 internal error. and also stating in the title "roundcube database connection failed" was pretty clear on what the error was.

Comment: did it solved the problem?

Comment: "tried jdbc and got 500 internal error" kind of answers your question.